# How can I play audio to people on a hangout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, google-hangouts

We have team-meetings via Google Hangouts regularly. In order to give it a theme-song or to set the mood, I would like to play an audio-file when all have gathered and the "official" part starts.

I have the audio in a MP3-file on my machine.

I use a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) with Google Chrome to connect to the video call.

I do not want to just crank up speakers and "redirect" the audio through the air to the microphone. A computer-internal software solution seems more appropriate. Any commandline-tool would be great. I have the feeling that gstreamer-something might help, but I do not understand how to achieve my goal.

So, how can I play audio to people on an hangout?

**UPDATE**

The mp3 I intend to play is freely available or I will get the rights for the intended usage. In any case, the legal ramifications of this are not part of the question.

**UPDATE**

I am still interested in a solution, currently using Ubuntu 16.04 (switching to 18.04 or 20.04 soon) and whatever Google calls their video-meeting then :-)

Comment: You want to do this without violating some copyright and infringement laws right?

Comment: the mp3 I have in mind is not copyrighted, but freely available. otherwise, sure, I would qualify as a radio station of some sort and would need to worry about paying royalties. I could also tell all participants to download it and instruct them to hit "play" at a certain point in time. FWIW, it could also be a self-recorded sound-bite of me singing. So, legal question are not part of this. however thanks for being a friend trying to keep me from trouble. :-)

Comment: Good to know, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Install Pulse Audio Volume Control `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
- Open Pulse Audio Volume Control Application
- Make sure, that no undesired sound emissions (notifications, other active speakers etc. are present.
- In Input Tab, switch the source of the recording Application to "Monitor of "
- Play sound through any music player
- Switch Source back to your microphone